# I can't insert my Edittext Multiline to Server

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to insert values to database mysqlserver, all values has been inserted succesfully except 'alamat' field.

i've tried to checked the declaration on Java File but i can't find the problem.

here is my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".InputSantriBaru"
    >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DataSantri"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DATA SANTRI"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NisSantri"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:layout_below="@id/DataSantri"
            android:hint="NIS Santri"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NamaDepan"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NisSantri"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:hint="Nama Depan"
            android:inputType="text"

            android:padding="10dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NamaBelakang"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NisSantri"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NamaDepan"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"

            android:hint="Nama Belakang" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TglLahir"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/NamaBelakang"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/NamaBelakang"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:hint="Tanggal Lahir"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TglGabung"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TglLahir"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:hint="Tanggal Gabung"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/AlamatSantri"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TglGabung"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DataOrangTua"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/AlamatSantri"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="DATA ORANG TUA"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NamaDepanOrtu"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DataOrangTua"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:hint="Nama Depan"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NamaBelakangOrtu"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DataOrangTua"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NamaDepanOrtu"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Nama Belakang" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EmailOrtu"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NamaDepanOrtu"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PasswordOrtu"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NamaBelakangOrtu"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EmailOrtu"
            android:background="@drawable/rounderborder"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password" />




        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/All_Okay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/EmailOrtu"
            android:text="Dengan ini saya menyatakan bahwa apa yang saya isi di atas sudah benar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Simpan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/All_Okay"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:onClick="Simpan"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my java

```
package com.budiluhur.almusyarrofahdigital;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class InputSantriBaru extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nis, namaDepan, namaBelakang, tglLahir, tglGabung, alamatSantri, namaDepanOrtu, namaBelakangOrtu, emailOrtu, password;
    private DatePickerDialog picker;
    private Button simpan;
    String ServerURL = "https://ohmybags.id/almus/CRUD.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_santri_baru);
        nis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NisSantri);
        namaDepan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NamaDepan);
        namaBelakang = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NamaBelakang);
        alamatSantri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AlamatSantri);
        namaDepanOrtu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NamaDepanOrtu);
        namaBelakangOrtu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NamaBelakangOrtu);
        emailOrtu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailOrtu);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordOrtu);
        tglGabung = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TglGabung);
        tglGabung.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        tglLahir = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TglLahir);
        simpan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Simpan);
        tglLahir.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        tglLahir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                //my date picker dialog
                picker = new DatePickerDialog(InputSantriBaru.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        tglLahir.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                    }
                }, year, month, day);
                picker.show();
            }
        });

        tglGabung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                //my date picker dialog
                picker = new DatePickerDialog(InputSantriBaru.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        tglGabung.setText((year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth));
                    }
                }, year, month, day);
                picker.show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void Simpan(View view) {

        String nis = this.nis.getText().toString();
        String namaDepan = this.namaDepan.getText().toString();
        String namaBelakang = this.namaBelakang.getText().toString();
        String tglLahir = this.tglLahir.getText().toString();
        String tglGabung = this.tglGabung.getText().toString();
        String alamat = this.alamatSantri.getText().toString();

        /*String namaDepanOrtu = this.namaDepanOrtu.getText().toString();
        String namaBelakangOrtu = this.namaBelakangOrtu.getText().toString();
        String emailOrtu = this.emailOrtu.getText().toString();
        String passwordOrtu = this.password.getText().toString();*/

        InsertData(nis,namaDepan,namaBelakang,tglLahir,tglGabung,alamat);


    }

    public void InsertData(final String nis, final String namaDepan, final String namaBelakang, final String tglLahir, final String tglGabung, final String alamat) {

        class SignInActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                String nisHolder = nis;
                String namaDepanHolder = namaDepan;
                String namaBelakangHolder = namaBelakang;
                String tglLahirHolder = tglLahir;
                String tglGabungHolder = tglGabung;
                String alamatHolder = alamat;
               /* String namaDepanOrtuHolder = namaDepanOrtu;
                String namaBelakangOrtuHolder = namaBelakangOrtu;
                String emailOrtuHolder = emailOrtu;
                String passwordOrtuHolder = passwordOrtu;
*/
                List<NameValuePair> NameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nis", nisHolder));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namaDepan", namaDepanHolder));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("namaBelakang", namaBelakangHolder));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tglLahir", tglLahirHolder));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tglGabung", tglGabungHolder));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alamat", alamatHolder));


                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(NameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(InputSantriBaru.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        SignInActivity sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SignInActivity();

        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(nis,namaDepan,namaBelakang,tglLahir,tglGabung,alamat);
    }

}
```

here is my php file

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

$machine = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

$nis = $_POST['nis'];
$namaDepan = $_POST['namaDepan'];
$namaBelakang = $_POST['namaBelakang'];
$tglLahir = $_POST['tglLahir'];
$tglGabung = $_POST['tglGabung'];
$alamat =' $_POST['alamat'];'
$statusIzin = 'dipondok';

$SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO `santri` (`nis`,`Nama_Depan`,`nama_belakang`,`tanggal_lahir`,`tanggal_bergabung`,`alamat`,`status_izin`) VALUES ('$nis','$namaDepan','$namaBelakang','$tglLahir','$tglGabung','$alamat','$statusIzin')";

if(mysqli_query($machine,$SQLQuery)){
    echo 'Data Berhasil Disimpan';
}else{
    echo 'try Again';

}




?>
```

all values inserted except "alamat" field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOjpm.png)

i didn't know where's the mistake was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please watch out this line of code in your backend side :

```
$alamat =' $_POST['alamat'];'
```

it should be :

```
$alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
```